# whoosh and blur sound effects

Tags: sound-design, sound-effects

I'm working on a commercial spot and need to come up with a good sound effect to go with a visual effect.  Here is the best way I can describe the visual effect:

The camera was on a circle dolly track moving around a family sitting on a couch.  At various times the dolly speeds up and we also ramped up the frame rate to speed up the visual.  It blurs (intentionally) then slows back to real time.

So, any ideas on a cool motion sound for a ramp up/ramp down of the frame rate and the camera move?  Hopefully this makes sense somewhat!

Answer (score 5):

Or try the Whoosh Anthology: http://thewhooshanthology.com/

Comment: Wow. Thanks for the link there. That Woosh library looks great.

Answer (score 4):

You should check out the "Swishes" library from Hiss and a Roar (http://hissandaroar.com/).  It might not have exactly what you are looking for but if you start with that as a base and put select ones through some processing (pitch shifting, time stretching, verb ect..) you will start to find what you are looking for I bet.  Good Luck.

Comment: I've been super impressed by this collection. Quality and variety is very good, and the sample rates are high enough that you can get really creative with it. I used it the other day to build wing flaps, and more. Worth every penny for the MAX version.

Answer (score 4):

I'd try reversing sounds with long decays & layering them with the tail of the forward sound.... so you can vary/control how aggressively the sound ramps

Comment: Gunshots are great for this.

Comment: lots of things are, including sounds that you record forwards, knowing you will reverse them ie the attack of what you perform becomes the decay.... perform accordingly

Comment: Ah yes, like Ben Burtt's (or Walter Murch) electric stick he made for THX which was a metal lamp shade.

Answer (score 3):

My first instinct would say to experiment with pitch bending some wind sounds. I know it might be a cliche but knowing the quick turnaround of commercials it could work.

Answer (score 2):

One trick I've messed about with in the past makes use of the Massey TD5 Tape Delay plugin (I'm sure there's plenty of other tools that do the same thing though). If you play some production sound or added sound fx from the scene through it 100% wet and then quickly move the delay amount slider when the whoosh happens you get a kind of vinyl spinback effect (if there's enough substance to the sound obviously) which can be quite effective sometimes, whether played by itself or alongside other whoosh fx.